# nServiceBus - Stops processing message intermediately

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

recently we upgraded our nServiceBus version to 7. Post this upgrade we are noticing that this endpoint stops processing messages intermediately.
We checked our logs and noticed below message there

```
Replication destinations cleared for url http://RavendbURL/databases/XXXBusDB. Failover servers count: 0
```

What could the reason of this message? And if this bringing down the endpoint?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think that message should stop message processing. If you are running a single instance of RavenDB it is expected that there would be zero failover servers. Does the endpoint crash or does it just stop processing messages? If possible, I would recommend sending a copy of the full log through to https://particular.net/support

Comment: 1. We have RavenDB hosted on a cluster. 2) You are right we checked it again, message processing does get stopped but after a while it restart processing on its own, which is bit weird. Sometime it starts processing after 5 minutes and sometime it is as long as 1 hour